# Laplace Expansion complexity calculation (recursion)

Tags: python, recursion, complexity-theory

Hey im having trouble calculating the complexity of [Laplace Expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm1fO.png) using my code:

```
def determinant_laplace(self, i=0):
    assert self.dim()[0] == self.dim()[1]
    if self.dim() == (1,1):
        return self[0,0]
    else:
        det = 0
        for col in range(self.dim()[1]):
            det += ((-1)**(col+i) *self[i,col]* self.minor(i,col).determinant_laplace())
        return det
```

to better undestand this here is how a minor is calculated (in my code):

```
def minor(self, i, j):
    t = self.dim()[0] # rows
    k = self.dim()[1] # columns
    assert isinstance(i, int) and isinstance(j, int) \
    and i < t and j < k
    newMat = Matrix(t-1,k-1) # new matrix will be with 1 less col and row
    for row in range(t):
        for col in range(k):
            if row < i and col < j:
                newMat[row,col] = self[row,col]
            elif row < i and col > j:
                newMat[row,col-1] = self[row,col]

            elif row > i and col < j:
                newMat[row-1,col] = self[row,col]

            elif row > i and col > j:
                newMat[row-1,col-1] = self[row,col]
    return newMat
```

as you can see, the complexity of creating a minor in nxn matrix is O(n^2).

so i'm torn by the overall complexity is it O(n!) or O((n+1)!) or O((n+2)!) ?

Why it's O(n!) : Wikipedia says so, but I guess their implementation is different and maybe they neglect some calculating regarding the minor.

**Why it's O((n+1))! : The recursion sequence is n(n^2 + next(recursion_minor)..) = O(n*n!) = O((n+1)!)**

Why it's O((n+2)!) : calculating a minor is O(n^2) and we calculate n! of those so we get O(n^2)*O(n!)=O(n+2)!

Personnaly I lean towards the **Bold** statement.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `O(n+2)!` is the right answer. 
as you mentioned the complexity to generate the minor `ij` for Matrix in size `n x n` is `O(n^2)` which derive from the slicing (`o(k)` in python) in your code. At the end of the Recursion you will get n! minors(in size `1 x 1`). So we got here:

```
O(n^2) * O(n!) = O(n!(n+1)(n+2)) = O(n+2)!
```

Comment: But isn't it also true that it doesnt take O(n^2) for every minor but it sequently decreases because the minors are getting smaller?

Answer (score 3):

Let `f(n)` be the time it takes for `determinant_laplace` to complete given any
square matrix of size `n` by `n`.

There are `n` minors to be computed.

For each minor it takes

- `O((n-1)**2) = O(n**2)` time to create the minor
- **plus** `f(n-1)` time to compute the `determinant_laplace` of the minor

So a recurrence inequality satisfied by `f` is:

```
f(n) <= n(C*n**2 + f(n-1))
```

for some `C` and for all `n` bigger than some constant `M`. I do not know what `C` and `M`
are, but we can take them to be known, constant values.

---

Consider the hypothesis `H(n)`:

```
f(n) <= D * n * n!
```

for some constant `D>0` which is independent of `n`.

---

Base cases: For `n = 1, ..., M`, we can find some constant `D` so huge such that

```
H(1), ..., H(M) are true, and D>C.
```

---

Preliminary observation: Note that `n**3/n! < 1` for `n >= 6`, and we can assume
without loss of generality that `M>6`.

---

Induction step: Take some `n > M` and assume `H(n-1)`.

```
f(n) <= n(C*n**2 + f(n-1))          # by our recurrence inequality
     <= C*n**3 + n*D*(n-1)*(n-1)!   # by H(n-1)
      = C*n**3 + D*(n-1)*n!
     <= C*n! + D*(n-1)*n!           # since n**3 / n! < 1 and n > M > 6
      = (C+D*(n-1))*n! 
     <= D*n*n!                      # since D > C
```

So `H(n)` is true. Therefore  `f(n)` is in `O(n*n!)`.

Note however, that this is a loose upper bound. Essentially the same induction proof can be used to show that `f(n)` is in `O(n**(1/p)*n!)` for any `p = 1, 2, 3, ...`.

Comment: Wait, I am not convinced of this.
Why is O(n!) = O((n+1)!) = O((n+2)!) ?
when n goes to infinity this is completely different...
by your claim it is also correct that: O(n) = O(n*(n+1)) which is obviously false.


Can you prove that this is correct by definition?

Comment: This proof is kinda 'risky'. If I assume O(f(n))=O((n+1)!) I would say O(f(n+1))=O((n+1)*(n^2+f(n))=O((n+1)*(n+1)!)=O((n+2)!). the induction is kind of 'broken' there are no base cases.
Can you explain this a bit more or explain why my statement above is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, I've been too sloppy. When I write out all the details, I get `f` in `O(n*n!)`, not `O(n!)`.